# .co domain worthy for main site?

Tags: domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.CO Domains. Worthwhile?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7209/co-domains-worthwhile)

Thought of a great name for the idea of my site, but the .com has already gone.

However the .co is available.

Is that common enough to use as the main domain for the site? It's a brand new site so it will be branded and promoted as sitename.co all the time.

Anyway have any .co?

Answer (score 0):

It will all be up to marketing, and trademarks.

This question is not really appropriate for Stack Overflow, though.